# How can I resize the image from sdcard before display it in gallery view?

Tags: android

If I put the normal size of images which stored in sdcard into a gallery view, it will be very slow so are there any way to resize it automatically before display it in gallery view?
Thanks.

```
private Gallery g;
private ImageView imv;

private Uri[] mUrls;
String[] mFiles=null;

class ImageFilter implements FilenameFilter
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return (name.endsWith(".JPG")|| name.endsWith(".jpg") );
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    File images = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/");
    File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new ImageFilter());

    mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];

    for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++){
        mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();
    }

    mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];

    for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++){
        mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);  
    }

    imv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);    

    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setFadingEdgeLength(40);  
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imv.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);              
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mUrls.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);            
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class MyImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private Drawable mImage;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    mImage =  Drawable.createFromPath("/sdcard/filename");

        mImage.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

to call this in your activity, setContentView(new MyImageView(this));

Comment: I just upload my code so may I ask you where do I need to put
"setContentView(new MyImageView(this));" in? Thanks a lot.

Comment: in your main activity instead setContentView(R.layout.main); write this setContentView(new MyImageView(this));

Comment: It force close when I do that.

Comment: 04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Mix/com.Mix.Galmix}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)

Comment: 04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: 04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at com.Mix.MyImageView.<init>(MyImageView.java:31)

Comment: 04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at com.Mix.Galmix.onCreate(Galmix.java:40)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
04-26 14:26:16.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25337):     ... 11 more

Is this it?

Comment: do one thing, put a image in res>drawable>imagename.png & create drawable folder in res if not exists 
instead writing mImage = Drawable.createFromPath("/sdcard/filename"); write this mImage=act.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("imag­­ename", "drawable", "packagename"));

Comment: I actually want an image that stored in sdcard instead of build-in image. What I'm trying to do is when I run this app, it will grab an image from specific folder which contain in sdcard and display it in a gallery view. But if the image stored in that folder are too big it will slow down the gallery view so I just need to resize an image in that folder to some smaller size(automatically). Do I still need to put an image in a res folder or not?

Comment: no, its jst an alternate way, u can create drawable from sdcard also & it is working for u now